# How to get the videos uploaded in youtube to my website using feeds - Google api version 3 V3)

Tags: drupal, youtube, drupal-7, google-api, feed

Hi I have been using the version 2 url to get the youtube feeds of a particular channel i manage and import into my drupal website using the feed importer module.

This is the [URL](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channel_name/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=50&alt=rss&orderby=published) i used,

Now it seems the **google api V2** has been depreciated.
Can anyone help me to get this update to the version 3?

Answer (score 0):

First: auch.. you already had a full year to create the new code for V3..

But: here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/

By using drupal I assume you are using php: (section: Retrieve my uploads)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads

(following the link will provide a example code..)